# Using an external function inside a lambda expression

Tags: c++, transform, std

Is it possible to call an external function inside a lambda expression and if not is there another way to do this using transform and the external function?

```
int half(int x) { return x / 2; }

int main() {
std::vector<int> test(5);
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), []() { return half(4); });
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [it is definitely possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58f5df453e5c5fc3). In fact, the only problem with your code is that your lambda should accept an `int`. With that fix, your code [compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ada01db982af103):

```
int half(int x) { return x / 2; }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> test(5);
    std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), [](int) { return half(4); });
    //                                                        ^^^
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jefffrey says, it's possible and common. However, `std::transform` takes either a unary operation or a binary operation as its final argument. You probably want something more like:

```
static int half(int x) { return x / 2; }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> test(5);
    std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), [](int value) {
        return half(value); 
    });
    return 0; 
}
```